# Liferay's Calendar : only select fields displayed

Tags: html, liferay, alloy-ui

in my jsp I am creating Calendar like this :

```
Calendar birthday = CalendarFactoryUtil.getCalendar();
```

and then displaying it like this :

```
<aui:input class="form-control" name="birthday" value="<%= birthday %>" />
```

In the result, I have 3 select fields, for : day, month, year and the Calendar button. When I click on the calendar button obviously calendar is shown and I can pick  date just like that.

Now I would like the calendar button not to be shown, I just need those 3 selects. Is it possible, how can I do that ?

UPDATE :

My code which creates this 'data-picker' looks like this :

```
     <div class="form-group">
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test=...>
                        <aui:input class="form-control" name="birthday" value="<%= birthday %>" />
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <aui:input class="form-control" name="birthdayMonth" type="hidden" value="<%= Calendar.JANUARY %>" />
                        <aui:input class="form-control" name="birthdayDay" type="hidden" value="1" />
                        <aui:input class="form-control" name="birthdayYear" type="hidden" value="1970" />
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
       </div>
```

So it looks like `<aui:input>` takes care for creating all of it - which is the reason why I don't know how this could be done.

Comment: Can you show the complete code and generated html? You can either hide it through CSS.

Comment: I've udpated my question, thought, I don' think it would be helpful, I guess aui:input creates it all and it's hidden for a programmer where it's actually done.

Comment: That's why, I asked you to expose generated code. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following style to hide Calendar icon:

```
.aui-datepicker-button-wrapper button {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Ahh I'm so lame.. well getting wiser everyday, of course it's the way it should be done, thank you very much

Comment: It happens in the earlier days. Everything take time to groom.